# Conceptual issue with paypal shopping cart variable pass-through

Tags: paypal

Have paypal-created shopping-cart buttons, all I want on my "success" page is to be able to read the product numbers purchased.  For instance, if a customer adds "Product001" and "Product033" to the cart, and the transaction goes through successfully, I want paypal to pass me those numbers back, and I want to know how to read them using php (or any other way) so that I can tell my MySQL database that those items were purchased by the customer logged in via php sessions at the time.  I've read much that skirted all around the issue, but is there a simple way to either read the variables created in the paypal button wizard or set up my own variables to make sure they are read through and therefore submitted to the success page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [get registration data on paypal pay now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032392/get-registration-data-on-paypal-pay-now) and other answers referencing PayPal IPN, as that sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

By utilizing PayPal IPN (and, if you want, XHR) on your end, you can pull for payment confirmation from PayPal before releasing a downloadable file / granting access to your service / shipping the item, etc.

Comment: This takes me to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/, which tells me the what but not the how.  HOW does Paypal transmit the information back, HOW do I ask it to verify, HOW do I retrieve the information (is it a simple $_REQUEST[''], etc)?  Can you give me some insight on this?

Comment: Left-hand side side navigation, under the 'Instant Payment Notification' heading contains lots more information, including the 'how'. I.e. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Comment: Well, I'm embarrassed.  Should have seen that myself.  One final question, if I may . . . as I understand it, paypal can redirect to a success page without any of this, but once you set up an ipn page it redirects to a listener script on that page.  That listener script requires the full Paypal APK in order to operate?  This is the only way to have a simple custom field pass to paypal and pass back?

Comment: No, IPN works separately from the return page. The return page is what your buyer gets returned to at the end of the payment, but that doesn't necessarily mean all buyers get returned to it (they may close their browser, see a timeout right when accessing your success page, etc) - so I would recommend an async solution which records the transaction state irrespective of what happens on the client side. Hence IPN. Yes, you can build a working system without it, but it'll be less reliable for it. IPN doesn't need an APK or SDK to operate, no. Just a file which accepts POST data and processes it.

Comment: Technically IPN is just a HTTP POST to a file on your end with a specific payload, which you send back to PayPal once to validate it's genuine, after which you can process its contents and update / insert an order on your end as appropriate (or send a custom email to the buyer). If you pass `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="somecustomvaluehere">` in your Buy Now button (or CUSTOM for API calls), this data is also returned in the `custom` key inside the IPN HTTP POST payload. Hope this clears it up.